# Cant push new project to bitbucket from Android studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I created a new project in Android Studio. But I can not push it to bitbucket (I fight with it for all day, nothing works).

I get this error:

```
Push to origin/master was rejected
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://aaa@bitbucket.org/bbb/ccc.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [rejected] (fetch first)
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
Done
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And this is what I do:

1. Android Studio (AS) -> New project
2. AS -> VCS -> Enable Version Control integration -> Git
3. AS -> VCS -> Git -> Remotes -> I added URL of repository I created in bitbucket
4. AS -> Right click on project => Git => Commit & Push - > ERROR

What is the problem? I dont understand the error message, I do not have any "another repository", it is just me working on this project, and it is newly created.

When I try to follow advice to PULL changes, it also does not work (I get another error). And when I try to google that one, I get another one and another one and I soon I get lost...its very complicated.

What am I doing wrong? All I want is just to push a new project to bitbucket...

Comment: Check if somebody pushed to master and your commit is behind. In this case `git fetch origin master` and then merge the code.

Comment: Nobody pushed anything - its brand new repo created by me, and brand new project created by me. ALso, nobody else has access to my bitbucket, only me.

Comment: I literally just did those 4 steps I mentioned above in my post, it took 2 minutes

Comment: I tried to use `git fetch origin master`. Now I get another error: `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
! refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [rejected] (non-fast-forward)
Done
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. I have no idea why git kept giving me those random errors (when both repo and project were fresh and just minutes old, those error messages ddint make much sense), but this is what helped:

```
git push -f --set-upstream origin master
```

I guess it is just another proof how complicated, and unintuitive git is.